# Know the changes of Schema and new tables between staging and production database

Tags: python, mysql

I have two mysql databases. One on staging server and another one on production server. Initially both were exactly same. Later some modifications made on staging database in terms of change in schema, adding or removing some tables etc. Now I need to compare staging server's database with the production database in terms of new tables and new columns made in existing tables.
I need to write a python script for the same by which I'll be login on both database and will compare both.
I am in learning phase and I don't know from where I need to start and how to do this. It would be a great help if someone can help me out.

Comment: you can use **liquibase** to compare the databases and to deploy new features

Comment: I don't want to know the changes about the datasets. I want to know if there are some tables which don't exist on production database but exists on staging. And if there is any column which does not exist on production database table but exists on staging database table.

Comment: correct ! it show you any change or missing tables , index and every thing else. They can also produce queries for you to update the database. see: http://www.liquibase.org/

Comment: I need to write a script to check the missing tables and missing columns in existing table.